# Is there a way to modify a Settings.Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So the thing is at work I was assigned an old project which basically reads data from a table in a database and that data that reads from the first table makes an update to a second table in another database and I was looking a file called Settings.Designer.cs which has auto generated code.

I was looking at the file and has the values which reads the data from (from the first table) and I saw the strings are "hardcoded"

[image: example]

is there a way to make those values dynamics values? Because this file is a **internal sealed partial class** and I have understood this types of classes can't be accessed

Comment: Settings.Designer.cs is an auto-generated file, it holds information about the Settings and there should be no need to change it manually. If you want to change the actual values you can set them in app or web.config

Comment: There should be a `Settings` file in your project. If you double-click it, there will (should) be a grid in the IDE where you can change the values. That's how `Settings.Designer.cs` gets (re)generated.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The thing is I wanted to make them "Dynamic" because sometimes changes are made in the table or the database, that was I was asking if there is a way, so the app updates the values from the Settings.Designer.cs. This saves me from having to change them every time an update is made in the table or databases

Comment: Well, you don't _have_ to read information from the settings - they can come from elsewhere. Settings are usually relatively static pieces of information that you nevertheless wish to have the opportunity to alter - e.g. logging levels or connection strings, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the settings as a general rule are generated from the project settings page:

so, in VS go project and the last option will be "my project name here" properties.

And then you see this:

[image]

So things like company name, connection strings, constant values and what not can be created, edited, and maintained from above.

It not clear if you attempted to see/use/look/change settings using above, or there are settings that exist in the desinger file that don't exist in above?

There "might" be a good case - but we assume you at least checked the above first???

I mean, if you add a connection string, or even just some particular constant, or even say some web site company name for the whole site?

When you build the project, those settings get shoved automatic and transferred into web.config for you.

So, at least give the settings page in your project a good look over before you do this. As a general rule, I would not modify that designer file until such time you are BEYOND 100% sure that is your only option. Remember, when you re-build the project, the designer file will get overwritten and re-created. You as a result will "lose" changes and settings as a result.

use the "source means" to work on that project, be it a simple webform, or what not, you want to REALLY try to use the VS built in design surfaces that in turn spit out, crank out those files, and to be honest - not looked at such files for 10+ years, and I never care about these types of generated bits and parts - since I as a developer don't have to create such files. They could be instructions for how to peel a banana for all I care. They are not my concern.

They should quite much be considered temporary files that are transient in nature - and changes to them in general will be lost on next project re-build.